# Could this code be re factored?

Tags: jquery, jquery-clone

I am using jquery to clone a div and the div has 3 input fields.
Since clone does not change the id and the name of the elements , I'm changing it by finding the element. I do this for each element.
Here is the code :

```
var idCounter = 1;
  var noOfClonedItems = 0;
  $('.container').on('click', '#add-new-sku', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var clonedItem = $('.sku-data:first').clone();

    clonedItem.find('#product_skus_attributes_0_price').attr('name','product[skus_attributes][' + idCounter + '][price]').val('0.0');
    clonedItem.find('#product_skus_attributes_0_price').attr('id','product[skus_attributes][' + idCounter + '][price]');

    clonedItem.find('#product_skus_attributes_0_units_in_stock').attr('name','product[skus_attributes][' + idCounter + '][units_in_stock]').val('0');
    clonedItem.find('#product_skus_attributes_0_units_in_stock').attr('id','product[skus_attributes][' + idCounter + '][units_in_stock]');

    clonedItem.find('#product_skus_attributes_0_units_sold').attr('name','product[skus_attributes][' + idCounter + '][units_sold]').val('0');
    clonedItem.find('#product_skus_attributes_0_units_sold').attr('id','product[skus_attributes][' + idCounter + '][units_sold]');

    clonedItem.appendTo('.sku-container');
    idCounter++;
    noOfClonedItems++;
  });
```

But I'm trying to optimize this technique , what if there are 100 elements ?

I am figuring out how this code can be optimized to work for any no of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks reasonable - what I would change is changing these lines:

```
clonedItem.find('#product_skus_attributes_0_price').attr('name','product[skus_attributes][' + idCounter + '][price]').val('0.0');
clonedItem.find('#product_skus_attributes_0_price').attr('id','product[skus_attributes][' + idCounter + '][price]');
```

to something like this:

```
clonedItem.find('#product_skus_attributes_0_price')
.attr('name','product[skus_attributes][' + idCounter + '][price]');
.attr('id','product[skus_attributes][' + idCounter + '][price]')
.val('0.0');
```

Other approach (instead of cloning objects) is to use some templating engine like http://embeddedjs.com/ or http://mustache.github.io/ they are really usefull when creating dom elements dynamically (and probably more productive).

Answer (score 0):

```
var noOfClonedItems = 0;

$('.container').on('click', '#add-new-sku', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var clonedItem = $('.sku-data:first').clone();
    clonedItem.find('[id^="product_skus_attributes"]').prop('id', function(_,id) {
        var name = 'product[skus_attributes][' + (noOfClonedItems+1) + ']['+id.split(/\d\_/).pop()+']';
        this.name = name;
        this.value = name=='price'?'0.0':'0';
        return name;
    }).appendTo('.sku-container');
    noOfClonedItems++;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rdDgY/)